# ASP.NET giving style to Linklabel

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, linklabel

I'm a novice at asp.net and I want to give style to a linklabel. My code as follows:

```html
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUser" runat="server" CssClass="userlabel">Guest</asp:LinkButton>
```

```css
.userlabel {
    display:inline-block;
    text-decoration: underline;
    background-color:coral;
}
```

I am suspicious about jQuery overrides Site.css code. Is it possible? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you have should work fine. Do you have a specific problem with it? The presence of jQuery alone won't interfere with CSS styles you apply.

Comment: Does it differ for css that Linklabel is in another section?

Comment: your css class doesn't apply on the linkbutton?

Comment: Does what differ? It's really not clear what you're asking, or even what the issue is

Comment: try !important to the css. so if style applies to the same element anywhere it will be override.

Comment: I mean, linklabel is in div>section>loginview. Should I define it to css file?

Comment: whatever it is, you can override it with !important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **!important** in css

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkUser" runat="server" CssClass="userlabel">Guest</asp:LinkButton>
```

Will render in html as:

```
<a id="lnkUser" class="userlabel" href="javascript:__doPostBack('lnkUser','')">Guest</a>
```

So you can add style for that like bellow to give importance

```
a.userlabel {
    display:inline-block !important;
    text-decoration: underline !important;
    background-color:coral !important;
}
```